# More confusion with relative pronoun ambiguity

Tags: ambiguity, syntactic-analysis, relative-pronouns

What does the relative pronoun refer to in this sentence?

> It was probably on the darker/smoother side of things, compared to, say, the Sony ZX-1, which I prefer.

To me, his preference isn’t clear. It can be inferred in context, but on its own, I think it is ambiguous.

Comment: I don't see any grounds for referential ambiguity here. I think _which_ in this sentence is unambiguously referring to the NP it follows, _the Sony ZX-1_. It's a nonrestrictive relative, but they use the same coreference strategies as restrictive. From context, one can infer that the subject pronoun _It_ is also a device of some sort, but it's at the other end of the sentence from the relative pronoun, and pronouns like _it_ normally don't get modified by non-restrictive relative clauses, let alone get those clauses teleported to the other end of the sentence by some mysterious rule.

Comment: Thank you - I thought that a relative pronoun always refers to the item immediately preceding it, but considered the possibility of exceptions. Some folks planted the ambiguity in my mind by arguing that 'which' clearly refers to 'It'. I should've known better because they came to their conclusions based on the context, not the syntax itself. They aren't grammarians (just headphone enthusiasts) and I'm a relatively inexperienced English teacher, so I'm not much better.

Comment: It almost always refers to the NP it follows, though there are exceptions, like Extraposition from NP: _Something came up [that caused concern]._ But that rule has very stringent conditions and they don't occur that often in discourse. BTW, as an English teacher, you're welcome to use any of the stuff I have [on my website](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler) in your classes.

Comment: Thank you, John. I'm sure I'll be able to find something that will help me develop my teaching skill.

Comment: The supplementary relative can also refer to the previous clause as a whole (or to part of it). And so, another possibility is that the person liked that the other device is on the smoother side of things--he has a preference for that kind of (smoother) stuff. Context is important in these types of sentences.

Comment: Reading it out of context, I leant toward the Sony ZX-1 being the thing preferred. Reading it in context, I lean toward being on the darker/smoother side of things being what is preferred. I can't really explain why. Oh well, apologies for the me-too.

Comment: Yes, Neil, it will depend on the context. What you have there is a supplementary relative clause, and often, it is the context that determines exactly what it was that the speaker meant as to the antecedent.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm not completely convinced... _It was probably on the darker/smoother side of things, compared to, say, explosive diarrhoea, which I prefer._ Or is that because I 'know' the context of _It_ ?

Comment: @Frank: Sorry, I have no idea of what you know, what you prefer, or how you understand coreference. Nor am I trying to convince you of anything; you're under no obligation to believe whatever it is I said that you're unconvinced of. It's your language, after all.

Comment: @JohnLawler At least that is unambiguous. ;)

Comment: @Aaron - see the edit to my answer for what the original author really meant. Not the ZX-1.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, the talker prefers "the Sony ZX-1".

Firstly, this sentence has a small punctuation error, which might cause some confusion. This sentence can completely change the meaning when using wrong punctuation.

One case would be like this (which is probably what you want to say):

> It was probably on the darker/smoother side of things compared to, say, the Sony ZX-1, which I prefer.

Note that there's no comma after "things". In this case, as there's a comma before "which" and after a noun, "which" refers to "the Sony ZX-1".

On the other hand, if the sentence was like this:

> It was probably on the darker/smoother side of things compared to, say, the Sony ZX-1 which I prefer.

Supposing that "it" refers to some other sort of product, "which" in this case would be referring to "it".

Hope this has been useful.

Comment: Actually, you kinda have it backwards. Your 2nd version uses an integrated relative clause--and so the relative modifies the Sony ZX-1. The 1st version uses a supplementary relative clause--its antecedent depends on the overall context, which can be part of or all of the preceding clause/sentence.

Comment: And I wouldn't consider a comma before _compared to…_ incorrect either. It can be there or not, its presence implying that the comparison is a bit of an afterthought and would be preceded by a small pause in speech.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. It is ambiguous. The two options are:

> It was probably on the darker/smoother side of things, [...] which I prefer.
>
> It was [...] compared to the Sony ZX-1, which I prefer.

This ambiguity is resolved by the surrounding context (the author prefers the darker/smoother side of things) but the complicated structure does not make this intuitively obvious.

The quickest fix is to use parentheses:

> It was on the darker/smoother side of things (compared to, say, the Sony ZX-1), which I prefer.

This keeps the fighting parentheticals in their own punctuation blocks and completely removes the ambiguity.

Comment: Is that the same as my answer? I have added what the original author actually said he meant (in the edit part).

Comment: @Frank: No, this *isn't* saying the same as your answer. You say that OP's author prefers "it", which (semantics aside) I think is not a syntactically credible interpretation. What MrHen is saying is the author prefers "the darker/smoother side of things", which seems like a perfectly acceptable way to interpret the ambiguous phrasing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah... I see what you mean, but than that's still not what the original author applied 'prefer' to. As you can see from the ETA in my answer, the original author of the quote says he preferred 'It' (the M/AK120) over the ZX-1. I don't think he worried too much about syntax or grammar when he wrote either the original quote or the follow-up explanation.

Comment: @Frank: Well, since the author specifically says "it" was probably associated with "the darker/smoother side of things", it's quite likely he *would* prefer "it". But that's a semantic extrapolation. Syntactically, I don't think you could reasonably infer "which" refers to "it" - if that's what the author *intended*, his writing leaves much to be desired.

Comment: @FumbleFingers `his writing leaves much to be desired` Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

It is ambiguous.

Notwithstanding the grammatical explanations of those who appear to have extensively studied the theory and terminology, the inclusion of colloquialisms such as "...compared to, say,..." takes the statement out of the realms of textbook grammar and into the area of the spoken language.

Spoken language, with its advantages of gestures, facial expressions, context etc, needs to be adjusted when written down to remove the inherent ambiguity of the words alone.

Ambiguous: "It was probably on the darker/smoother side of things, compared to, say, the Sony ZX-1, which I prefer."

Unambiguous: It was probably on the darker/smoother side of things, compared to, say, my preferred device, the Sony ZX-1.

Unambiguous: Compared to, say, the Sony ZX-1, it was probably on the darker/smoother side of things, which I prefer.

Answer (score -4):

If you treat the commas are parenthetical then your original sentence means '*It* is preferred over a Sony ZX-1'.

While I don't disagree entirely with John Lawler's coreferential comment, I think that's expecting a lot of Joe Public who is much more used to using commas in the parenthetical.

Reducing the sentence, parenthetically ...

> It was probably on the darker/smoother side of things, compared to, say, the Sony ZX-1, which I prefer.

Get rid of the inner parenthesis

> It was probably on the darker/smoother side of things, compared to the Sony ZX-1, which I prefer.

Get rid of the inner parenthesis

> It was probably on the darker/smoother side of things which I prefer.

Add in another bit of punctuation because, well, who knows, but there is a natural pause there and ...

> It was probably on the darker/smoother side of things, which I prefer.

Your sentence author prefers *It*.

---

Out of interest - You know the context; so what was *It*, and is it preferable to the Sony ZX-1 (in terms of darker/smoother), bearing in mind that not everyone knows (or applies) the rules that John Lawler knows.

---

**ETA:**
Unlike most of these 'what did the original author really mean questions' it turns out that there is clarification from the original author.

Did he prefer the ZX-1 or *It*? Well I think this explains it

> I prefer the M and the AK120 for preference over the ZX-1, even after the update.

You can find this at http://www.head-fi.org/t/687944/999-calyx-m-with-dxd-dsd-64gb-sd-sd-storage/2670#post_10540041

Case closed.